# Why am I getting "Can't mass-assign protected attributes" after adding a field to a product on spree?

Tags: spree

I'm trying to add a field to products on spree which is just a checkbox which is just ment to mark products if they are for sale or they're internal products.

I've added the migration and finally figured out how to add the checkbox on the form, but when I click Update I get `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: for_sale`

This is the migration

```
class AddProductForSaleField < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :spree_products, :for_sale, :boolean
  end
  def down
    remove_column :spree_products, :for_sale
  end
end
```

Here's the field being added

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path  => "spree/admin/products/_form",
                     :name          => "for_sale",
                     :insert_before => "code[erb-silent]:contains('track_inventory_levels')",
                     :partial       => "spree/admin/products/for_sale")
```

And this is the partial

```
<%= f.field_container :for_sale do %>
    <%= f.label :for_sale, t(:for_sale) %>
    <%= f.check_box :for_sale, { :checked => true } %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got it, was missing the model part

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do 
    attr_accessible :for_sale
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Mass Assignment is the name Rails gives to the act of constructing your object with a parameters hash. It is "mass assignment" in that you are assigning multiple values to attributes via a single assignment operator.

The following snippets perform mass assignment of the name and topic attribute of the Post model:

Post.new(:name => "John", :topic => "Something")

Post.create(:name => "John", :topic => "Something")

Post.update_attributes(:name => "John", :topic => "Something")

In order for this to work, your model must allow mass assignments for each attribute in the hash you're passing in.

There are two situations in which this will fail:

You have an attr_accessible declaration which does not include :name

You have an attr_protected which does include :name

It recently became the default that attributes had to be manually white-listed via a attr_accessible in order for mass assignment to succeed. Prior to this, the default was for attributes to be assignable unless they were explicitly black-listed attr_protected or any other attribute was white-listed with attr_acessible.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a permission issue then you can add :

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do 

  attr_accessible :variable_1, :variable_2 :as => [:default, :product]

end
```

Marking it as default for a specific model, will remove the mass-assignment warning message !